# How to fix npm vulnerabilities?

Tags: security, npm

Right now `npm audit` shows

```
88 vulnerabilities (82 moderate, 6 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

I have tried `npm audit fix --force`, the number of vulnerabilities comes down to 40. When I try to run the application it fails. I have tried deleting `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` then running `npm install` but that does not fix it.

[image: picture of the audit problem]

How can I resolve this issue?