# Fixing npm vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js, dependencies, npm-audit, npm-vulnerabilities, dependency-tree

I am following a TypeScript tutorial. 
Unfortunately, the packages are outdated and I got a warning about vulnerabilities.

I followed a bunch of suggestions from [npm check and update package if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16525430), namely:

- `npm audit fix`
- `npm audit fix --force`
- `npm update`

`npm audit` says there are still 24 vulnerabilities left. 
But none of the above commands will fix them.

`npm outdated` results in no output.

The vulnerable packages are :

```
ansi-regex
glob-parent
node-forge
nth-check
postcss
```

I don't actually know why they are part of my project.
I don't have them in my `package.json`.

What are the next steps for fixing these vulnerabilities?

Below is what I have tried.

- [How to fix npm vulnerabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67679757) which has no answers.
- Manually updating the dependencies in `package.json` to newer versions and then running `npm install`. It didn't have an effect.
- Deleting `package-lock.json` as suggested [here](https://itnext.io/fixing-security-vulnerabilities-in-npm-dependencies-in-less-than-3-mins-a53af735261d) and then running `npm install` again.
- Adding `"ansi-regex": "^6.0.1", "glob-parent": "^6.0.2", "node-forge": "^1.3.0", "nth-check": "^2.0.1", "postcss": "^8.4.12"` as devDependencies and running `npm install`.
- Running `npm i npm@latest` as suggested in [How to fix npm vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67697844).
- [How to fix npm vulnerabilities? I tried two methods, problems persist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68172407) 
  which didn't have any new suggestions.
- [I have 5 moderate severity vulnerabilities when I checked the npm audit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69030314) 
  which also didn't suggest any new commands.
- Running `npm update glob-parent --depth 2` just to find out that `--depth` is deprecated and that npm always [updates any depth [GitHub]](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/main/implemented/0019-remove-update-depth-option.md).
- Running [`npm prune`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-prune).
- Deleting the `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again.

You can reproduce my latest state with the following `package.json` in an empty directory and running `npm install`.

```json
{
  "name": "pacman",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "I just follow a tutorial. Nothing of interest.",
  "keywords": ["game"],
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "someone stupid",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "parcel build index.html",
    "dev": "parcel index.html --open",
    "start": "npm run build && npm run dev",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.16.0",
    "ansi-regex": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "glob-parent": "^6.0.2",
    "node-forge": "^1.3.0",
    "nth-check": "^2.0.1",
    "parcel": "^2.4.0",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.12",
    "prettier": "^2.6.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "npm": "^8.5.5"
  }
}
```

This should give you 24 vulnerabilities, 18 moderate and 6 high, at the time of writing, running npm version 8.5.5.

Comment: At a certain point, maybe you _can't_ fix them. Are there actually fixed versions compatible with your other local dependencies?

Comment: @jonrsharpe So people simply release their software with vulnerabilities in place?

Comment: Yes, of course, although they don't necessarily know it at the time.

Comment: Fundamentally this is a dupe of what you've already found in the general case and you don't give enough information to solve (or more likely tell you exactly why you can't) in the specific case. `npm ls <package>` will tell you what version(s) of a package are required in your dependency tree, likely you have a transitive dependency on a vulnerable version without a semver-compatible fix, so installing a newer version directly wouldn't be expected to help.

Comment: We need a [mre]. How can someone else reproduce the problem locally? What's the least you can put into an empty directory such that `npm audit` recreates (maybe _one of_) the warnings on a vulnerable dependency. If you're just running through a tutorial, though (or they're e.g. development deps), do the warnings even _matter_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: probably I can get through the tutorial by ignoring the warnings. It's just that I don't like vulnerabilites and IMHO part of the learning experience should be to know how to resolve them. I have written an answer. Does it make sense what I did there?

Comment: It's _reproducible_, anyway... `npm init -y && npm i parcel-bundler@1` -> `24 vulnerabilities (19 moderate, 5 high)`. Or e.g. `npm ls node-forge` on what you posted, as suggested above, would show that despite the direct dependency on `1.3.0`, you have a transitive dependency on `0.10.0` via `parcel-bundler`.

Comment: *I just follow a tutorial.*
Would you mind telling what tutorial you were following that led to this question?
The main reason I ask is that you have added the packages ansi-regex, glob-parent, node-forge, nth-check, postcss as direct dependencies to the original `package.json`.
Were the direct dependencies `parcel`  and `parcel-bundler` included in the original
`package.json`? Or did you add them later?

Comment: @Henke: it was a Pacman tutorial, but I can't remember which one. I don't have the link any more. From the commit history of the project,the first commit already contains the fixed packages. It seems I never committed the broken version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments, I have already tried all commands for the general case, in which case you need to start analyzing individual packages.

So, what did I do?

1. Update all dependencies to the latest version.

Next, perform a binary search by removing half of the dependencies and repeating the following steps

2. delete the `node_modules` folder
3. run `npm install`
4. run `npm audit` to check for the vulnerabilities

If there are no vulnerabilites, add the half of the remaining packages you want to install.

If there are vulnerabilities, remove the half of the packages you are currently installing.

In my case, this process boiled it down to the following two lines:

```
"parcel": "^2.4.0",
"parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5",
```

For `parcel-bundler`, NPM spit out a warning:

```
npm WARN deprecated parcel-bundler@1.12.5: Parcel v1 is no longer maintained. 
Please migrate to v2, which is published under the 'parcel' package.
```

So I guess I don't need `parcel-bundler` at all, because it has been integrated into the `parcel` package, which I had already updated to version 2 in an earlier step.

Comment: Ah, the old binary search

Answer (score 1):

Try to **update** all your npm with this command. It helped me

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Comment: the OP tried this without the global tag. would it make a difference?

Answer (score -1):

As noted in [your self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71635482), the `parcel-bundler` package is deprecated :

> [Parcel v1 is no longer maintained. Please migrate to v2, which is published under the 'parcel' package.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-bundler/v/latest)

[image: The parcel-bundler package is deprecated.]

In fact, [the npm package *name has changed* from `parcel-bundler` to `parcel`](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/migration).
Having them both in the same `package.json` means having two different versions of the exact same package twice, so the word *deprecated* is rather misleading in this case.

#### Reproducing your findings – can we trust the audit report?

Thanks for including the `package.json` in your question. 
Doing so makes it possible to [reproduce your findings](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

1. I run [`npm install npm@latest -g`](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities), and then `npm --version`, which responds `10.2.3`.
2. In an empty directory, I add a version of your `package.json`, then run `npm install`. <sup>1</sup>

`package.json` :

```json
{
  "name": "soq-71635274-fix-npm",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "parcel": "^2.4.0",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5",
    "prettier": "^2.6.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  }
}
```

3. To make sure I have the latest versions of all packages, I then run [`npx npm-check-updates`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates/v/latest#installation), followed by `npx npm-check-updates -u` and `npm install`. 
   The response says `59 vulnerabilities (47 moderate, 12 high)`, 
   and suggests to "Run `npm audit` for details".
4. So next I run `npm audit`.
   Here is the beginning of the resulting [npm audit security report](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-audit-reports).

[image: Start of npm audit security report, at first.]

```
# npm audit report
glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: high
…
```

5. Since `parcel-bundler` is obsolete, I remove it from `package.json`. 
   But running  `npm install` doesn't give a clean report. 
   It still says `11 moderate severity vulnerabilities`.
6. Running `npm audit fix` neither changes `package.json` nor `package-lock.json`.
7. Running `npm audit fix --force` *once* downgrades `parcel` in `package.json` from `^2.10.2` to `^1.12.4`.
   The size of `package-lock.json` *increases* from 255 kB to 477 kB.
8. Running `npm audit fix --force` *twice* (a second time) re-upgrades `parcel` from `^1.12.4` back to `^2.10.2` in `package.json`. 
   It *decreases* the size of `package-lock.json` from 477 kB to 184 kB. <sup>2</sup>

This also results in `found 0 vulnerabilities` :

[image: Finally, 'found 0 vulnerabilities']

I find this remarkable. 
Fixing all the vulnerabilities and running  `npm install` is not enough to get a clean report. 
You then also need to run `npm audit fix --force` *twice*. <sup>3</sup>

### References

- [An answer explaining that `parcel-bundler` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71635482)
- [The package `parcel-bundler` is deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-bundler/v/latest)
- [How to migrate `parcel-bundler`](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/migration)
- [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- [Auditing package dependencies for security vulnerabilities](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities)
- [npm audit security report](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-audit-reports)

---

<sup>1</sup>
Since you added the packages `ansi-regex`, `glob-parent`, `node-forge`, `nth-check`, and `postcss` as *direct* devDependencies, I decided to *undo* that by removing them from `package.json`. 
I also removed the dependency on `npm@^8.5.5`, which I believe stems from you running `npm i npm@latest` which installs `npm` *locally*.
By contrast, I always install `npm` only *globally*, `npm i npm --global`.

<sup>2</sup>
The only difference in `package-lock.json` *before* running `npm audit fix --force` and *after* running it twice, is that a lot of packages have been removed.
I'd assume that the ones removed are packages that `parcel-bundler` depends on. Thus, `npm install` alone does *not* remove these packages.

<sup>3</sup>
Running `npm audit fix --force` a *third* time does *not* change `package.json` or `package-lock.json` anymore. 
It seems that once a state of *"0 vulnerabilities"* is reached, the command `npm audit fix --force` doesn't induce any more changes.
This makes sense.